# How can I determine if a node module can be bundled using Webpack and run in a browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Webpack has the ability to bundle up node modules which can then be loaded in an html page and used in the browser. But not all node modules can be used this way. For example, those that use the 'fs' module, or any other module that needs to break outside the browser sandbox or depends on such a module.

So my question: Is there a straightforward way to determine if a module can be used in the browser, short of trying it out?

I'm developing a web application that uses Webpack and I need libraries for all sorts of things. Usually the libraries I find are packaged as node modules and I have had reasonable success at using them.  However, I'm never quite sure when I encounter a library, whether it will actually work on the browser, without having to try them out each time. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source code, readme are good places to start. Based on the functionality, you can also take a good guess as to whether it'll work on client or not. Any OS dependent stuff like file i/o, databases etc can be ruled out easily. Others need a deeper inspection.

Another place to look for is whether their API has an equivalent HTML5 API (like fetch API -> iso-fetch and so on). Use MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide) to find out about equivalent APIs.

When in doubt, ask the developers - raise an issue or go to their prescribed medium of communication (chat/gitter/slack etc.).

This question is very general in nature, hence the answer cannot be a specific one. And no, there is no shortcut way of figuring this out, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Generally the same library indicate whether is server-side or client-side, for example:

> [PageJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/page): Tiny Express-inspired client-side router.

Also and good alternative, maybe you are looking for frontend exclusive libraries:

> [Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower) offers a generic, unopinionated solution to the problem of front-end package management

Hope to help you!